# Inserting time values in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I enter TIME values inside my database table's "departTime" column.
But I don't need "seconds" values, I only need "hh:mm" values.
But when I enter TIME as "07:25", I get error, phpMyAdmin tells me to enter as "07:25:00". Is it possible to omit seconds?

Another option is using VARCHAR or other field type. But I have such query "`SELECT * FROM table WHERE departTime >= $startTime AND departTime <= $stopTime`"

I have `$startTime = "14:15"` and `$stopTime = "16:00"`. If I use VARCHAR I couldn't compare the time values? What would be better option, except entering each seconds values by hand ?

Edit: This works: `UPDATE table SET`departTime`= "16:00" WHERE id = 12;`
But this doesn't work: `INSERT INTO table (`departTime`) VALUES ("16:00");`

Comment: is it that difficult to add ":00" on the end of the time values?

Comment: It is allowing me to enter time like "07:25" when I define column data-type as TIME. I am using phpmyadmin version 3.1.1

Comment: @Jaitsu I have hundreds of rows to enter by hand :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a script to do this for you... Enterring thousands of rows by hand is crazy!

Comment: What type is you `departTime` column? Which version of PhpMyAdmin are you running? Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @YaK departTime is TIME. phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2. MySQL 5.5.27. PHP 5.4.7. Apache/2.4.3.

Comment: Weird. I have virtually the same setup here, and I can insert "16:00"... `INSERT INTO table (departTime) VALUES ("16:00");` also works in both PhpMyAdmin and the console client. Have you also tried in the console client?